# How to check if my ML trainingscode with Tensorflow was correct?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to train my csv data using Tensorflow (TF). Since, I'm new in TF, I dont know if my code is correct.

What i want to do is to make a prediction which letter is show. For example if i show letter `A`, the letter `A` should be shown. So for that i've created a csv file which contains the class and the coordinates of each letter. The column `class` resemble the Letters, like `0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'` and so on.

```
class    x1        y1     ...     y21       z21 
0     0.187087  0.668525  ... -0.024700  0.220235 
1     0.202503  0.669253  ... -0.107100  0.240229 
....
2     0.248009  0.676325  ... -0.070317  0.278087  
2     0.245750  0.658381  ... -0.077429  0.282217 
3     0.235889  0.643202  ... -0.080697  0.262705

[20357 rows x 64 columns]
```

Know I want to check if my training modell is correct or is there something wrong. How can I do that? Because when I load and output my `tfmodel.h5` I always get wrong values.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                4096      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 31)                3999      
=================================================================
Total params: 16,415
Trainable params: 16,415
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: In machine learning, there's nothing right or wrong as your training proceed. When we talk about machine learning, it's mostly about whether it's precise/accurate or not. As you can get high accuracy, precision, and some other evaluation metrics and get the loss lower, you are on the right track.

Comment: @DhanaD. Thx for your comment. If i output my model, I'm always getting a high probability but still the letter which should be schown is false. What can I do to get a better accurancy and prediction?

Comment: Have you splitted your dataset and evaluate with test set? It's probably due to overfitting tho. It also depends on how many cases it occured

Comment: Great. if you use the test as validation set during training, you should compare the training accuracy vs validation accuracy, if the validation accuracy is too low, it's the sign of overfitting.

Comment: I've used `model.evaluate` with a `batch _size=128` to get loss and accurancy for X_test, y_test: `[0.06063482165336609, 0.9958520531654358]` and for X_train, ytrain:`[2.947278153442312e-05, 1.0]`. I've also generate predictions for 10 samples and im getting this: `(10, 28)`. Does it mean that my training is overfitting? becaus I'm curious about the value of X_train.

Comment: It's nothing wrong with model. As the number of mistakes done by model is not so much, it's still acceptable. You may need to add variation for your data.

Comment: What do you mean by adding variaton on my data?

Comment: The more data that covers more kind of possible cases..

Comment: Ok thx i will try to feed my csv file with more data.

Comment: The accuracy which you have mentioned you should be getting almost correct predictions all the time, to understand it more better could you provide some code and distribution details of your data.